# Image doesn't Dispaly On Run Time

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

I am using below code for display image in Image button in silverlight.

My problem is the Image Getting display on Design Time.

But I cant able to view that Image on Runtime.What are the changes need to solve the issue and I tried to using both (Front and Back) slashes.

```
Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="155" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" Source="C:/Users/Username01/Desktop/Lync.png"/>
```

Comment: there is issue with the area where you are displaying this image, where you are showing this image.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh I dispaly that image inside of the Grid

Comment: try width= auto, and do you hav any column or row definitions?

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh No,I didnt have ROw or column Definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way if it showing error, make a folder in your project thorugh visual studio add, images to that folder and pass the path like this: `<Image Source="Images\Lync.png" Stretch="Fill"/>`